# Posting an xml document, but not via a request parameter but in the body

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I am currently posted an xml file to a url using this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/post/here");

File f = new File("/path/to/file/file.txt");
String str = Files.toString(f, Charset,defaultCharset());

List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("payload", xmlFile));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

But this is adding a request parameter of "payload" such that when I want to receive the value in my doPost servlet I will do:

```
request.getParameter("payload");
```

I'm guessing this parameter "payload" is in the request header?

What I want to do is have this file sent in the body of the request, so in my doPost I will have to get the data from the stream, i.e.:

```
... = request.getInputStream();
```

How can I modify my code to do this? (using httpclient)

Also, can someone explain the differences between the 2 when it comes to format of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apache documentation on HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Request_Response_entity_streaming) has an example of streaming data in a request:

```
public class FileRequestEntity implements RequestEntity {

    private File file = null;

    public FileRequestEntity(File file) {
        super();
        this.file = file;
    }

    public boolean isRepeatable() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    }

    public void writeRequest(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(this.file);
        try {
            int l;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((l = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, l);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    public long getContentLength() {
        return file.length();
    }
}

File myfile = new File("myfile.txt");
PostMethod httppost = new PostMethod("/stuff");
httppost.setRequestEntity(new FileRequestEntity(myfile));
```

As to the difference of the two, they both store the data in the body of the HTTP request. As an [example](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod), the following is a standard HTTP POST request with two URL encoded parameters (`home` and `favorite flavor`). Using the input stream directly will also be slightly more efficient as there is no need for parsing the parameters.

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies
```